# Angular Observable being called multiple times

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have a service in which I defined a global observable like so:

```
 @Injectable()
  export class XYZService {
    country: Observable<any>;
    isBrowser: boolean;

    constructor(private http: Http,
                private httpClient: HttpClient,
                private router: Router,
                @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any) {
      this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
      if(this.isBrowser && !this.country) {
      this.country = this.http.get('https://ipinfo.io')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(() => {
          return Observable.of({'country': 'SG'});
        }); 
      };
    }

    getLocation(): Observable<any> {
      return this.country;
    }
```

Now in several of my components I'm calling the getLocation function in the constructor or ngOnInit like so:

```
this.XYZService.getLocation()
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.country = res['country'];
});
```

My expectation is that the request to ipinfo.io would only be made once. However that is not happening. From the network logs I can see that the request to ipinfo is being made multiple times. Looks to be some timing issue. If I add a debugger or console.log statement within the constructor, it is only called once. However more than one request are sent.

Comment: I wonder why you are using Http and HttpClient together? both of them has a different implementation, I suggest you use just the HttpClient and then try.

Comment: It's not a timing issue. It's how observables work. To cache the result, you would have to use `publishReplay().refCount()`: http://plnkr.co/edit/rvucIT6DF6nZmqNP7zzT?p=preview. Read http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#multicasted-observables

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the rxjs [share](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md) operator. This will ensure that subsequent subscribers will share the same observable sequence (until the number of observers returns to 0)

```
this.country = this.http.get('https://ipinfo.io')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch(() => {
      return Observable.of({'country': 'SG'});
    })
    .share();
```

You can also use the [shareReplay](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/sharereplay.md) operator. The difference is the observable result will be stored for any subscribers in the future. For example say you subscribe to the observable when the app loads, with `shareReplay` when you subscribe 10+ minutes later, the observable will return the same result and not make another http request. Whereas with `share`, the number of observers returns to 0 after the initial http request finishes. The future subscribe will trigger another http request